# MySQL Cursor Not Working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I am going nuts about this problem.

The stored procedure below opens a cursor, and then iterates over the result to do some inserts.

The select statement used for the cursor works when used outside a cursor (in the sql window). However it does not *work* in the cursor, the cursor returns NULL when opened!

Do note that this code is in a stored proc., that is itself called by another stored procedure which is opening another cursor. Not sure if this info. is useful.

```
DECLARE location VARCHAR(255);                      -- location
DECLARE isLocationDone BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;   -- status flag
DECLARE curLocation CURSOR FOR
    SELECT `LOCATION` AS loc FROM `mfdtemp`.`opexstk_tmp`
    WHERE `client` = in_client AND DATE(`rentdat`) < in_date
    ORDER BY loc;
DECLARE 
    CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET isLocationDone = TRUE;

OPEN curLocation;

label_location_loop: LOOP

    FETCH curLocation INTO location;

    IF isLocationDone THEN
        CLOSE curLocation;
        LEAVE label_location_loop;
    END IF;


    INSERT INTO t01_stock_report_htry (
        t01date, t01client, t01desc 
    ) 
    VALUES (in_date, in_client, CONCAT_WS('', 'Stack ', location)
    );

END LOOP;
```

Comment: I figured. Not sure if it is a MySQL bug, but it is pretty insidious.

The cursor was not working because I had declared a variable *location* and my cursor was using a field also called *`LOCATION`*.

Once I renamed the variable the cursor was working.

Comment: thanks for the help. It solved my case too. What a dumb behavior I should mention..

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html)?

```
INSERT INTO t01_stock_report_htry (t01date, t01client, t01desc)
  SELECT   in_date, in_client, CONCAT('Stack ', LOCATION)
  FROM     mfdtemp.opexstk_tmp
  WHERE    client = in_client AND DATE(rentdat) < in_date
  ORDER BY LOCATION
```

Comment: Don't bother about the INSERT statement, it is for illustrative purposes only. My issue is with the cursor.

Comment: @Telemat: Perhaps a better illustration would be one that shows how you're determining that "*the cursor returns NULL when opened*"?

Comment: @Telemat: that's not a bug, that's expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so simple that you will laugh at least once.

Please press **Insert Button** on the keyboard of your Pc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).